# Data from view model not binding to view - Xamarin Forms, Reactive UI

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, reactiveui

Welcome, I'm trying to bind array of strings to collection view item source, but it seems like my view model can't pass data, or isn't activated at all. I'm stuck at this moment. I tried to search on the internet and couldnt find any solution, also tried exacly as shown in the reactive ui sample, and stil same results, or should I say, no results.

View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xamForms:ReactiveContentPage x:TypeArguments="dashboard:DashboardViewModel" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                              xmlns:xamForms="clr-namespace:ReactiveUI.XamForms;assembly=ReactiveUI.XamForms"
                              xmlns:dashboard="clr-namespace:RoutinesTracker.Pages.Dashboard;assembly=RoutinesTracker"
                              x:Class="RoutinesTracker.Pages.Dashboard.DashboardView"
                              Title="Home"
                              BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Padding="15, 20">
            
            <CollectionView x:Name="ExampleCollectionView">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Frame 
                                CornerRadius="15" 
                                HasShadow="False"
                                BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageElementColor}"
                                Margin="0, 5">
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding}"
                                           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                           HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                                           TextColor="{DynamicResource PrimaryTextColor}"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</xamForms:ReactiveContentPage>
```

View.cs

```
using ReactiveUI;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace RoutinesTracker.Pages.Dashboard
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class DashboardView
    {
        public DashboardView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.WhenActivated(disposable =>
            {
                this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.ExampleCollectionList, v => v.ExampleCollectionView.ItemsSource);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
using Prism.Navigation;
using RoutinesTracker.Core.Layout.ViewModels;

namespace RoutinesTracker.Pages.Dashboard
{
    public abstract class DashboardViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public string[] ExampleCollectionList { get; set; }

        protected DashboardViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
        {
            ExampleCollectionList = new[]
            {
                "Item 1",
                "Item 2",
                "Item 3",
                "Item 4",
                "Item 5"
            };
        }
    }
}
```

And if anyone need, ViewModelBase class:

```
using Prism.Navigation;
using ReactiveUI;

namespace RoutinesTracker.Core.Layout.ViewModels
{
    public abstract class ViewModelBase : ReactiveObject
    {
        private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;

        protected ViewModelBase(INavigationService navigationService) => _navigationService = navigationService;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missed add ItemSource on CollectionView.
Try this

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ExampleCollectionList }" />
```

Comment: Since it's build with reactive ui, should be already binded by `this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.ExampleCollectionList, v => v.ExampleCollectionView.ItemsSource);` :/

Comment: You can try binding directly to see if works or not. If work, it means binding process got issue. I checked the document. I doubt you may need to use an observable collection to do the work , check this [link](https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/collections/).  And [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70028057/wpf-reactiveui-binding-listbox-itemssource-to-readonlyobservablecollection-not-w) although it's under WPF.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the ViewModel property of the view is null since you are not creating one explicitly.

You have to somehow populate the ViewModel property with a new DashboardViewModel. You can either just create one in the constructor of your view

```cs
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class DashboardView
    {
        public DashboardView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ViewModel = new DashboardViewModel();

            this.WhenActivated(disposable =>
            {
                this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.ExampleCollectionList, v => v.ExampleCollectionView.ItemsSource);
            });
        }
    }
```

Or you can use ViewLocation. There is one version used here https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/getting-started/compelling-example#create-views that uses reflection to find ViewModels for everything that implements IViewFor

```cs
Locator.CurrentMutable.RegisterViewsForViewModels(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
```

Or you could register them manually like so:

```cs
Locator.CurrentMutable.Register(() => new ToasterView(), typeof(IViewFor<ToasterViewModel>));
```

Here is a sample app that uses ViewModelRouting and registers the views in an AppBootstrapper class: https://github.com/GiusepeCasagrande/RoutingSimpleSample/blob/master/RoutingSimpleSample/RoutingSimpleSample/AppBootstrapper.cs